# anonymize IP with GTM using angular app

Tags: angular, google-tag-manager

I am using GTM in my Angular 4 app and it works fine, expect for one issue. I want to anonymize user IP, the piece of code I found says to add this to your code

```
ga('create', 'UA-********-1', '*****.com');
ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

However GTM provided me with the following code which doesn't have that bit, plus as I use angular as it is a SPA   `ga('send', 'pageview');` isn't useful. How can I anonymizeIP in the following code?

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-xxxxxx');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sign in to GTM, edit your universal analytics tag and find "fields to set", you can set it there.

Comment: How do I do that? Isn’t Universal Analytics pre configured triggered in list of triggers by google?

Comment: If you have GA working with a SPA you must've taken one of these approaches already: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/single-page-web-app-with-google-tag-manager/  scroll down to "things to keep in mind", that's the screen where you can see "fields to set" in tag settings.

Comment: GA is not preconfigured in GTM. You need to add the tag (there is a template where you can add your tracking id and other settings) and create a trigger so the tag executes (with an SPA that would probably be a history change trigger).

Comment: @EikePierstorff yes I am doing that. But now how do I test if anonymizeIp is working?

Comment: @Nofel, look at the GA request and see if the &aip parameter is set.

Comment: Great, thanks. Found [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) that helped.

Comment: @funkizer funny how our eyes cannot see that very thing for first time.